# Is frequency analysis the only attack on a simple substitution cipher?

Tags: frequency-analysis

I understand that "anagramming" is often used after frequency analysis of a traditional substitution cipher, but anagramming requires prior frequency analysis to provide a starting point. Is there any technique other than frequency analysis for a cipher-text only attack on a traditional substitution cipher?

Comment: Brute force, maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are many. Here are the few that I know:

1. [Brute-Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack): Simply trying all possible keys.
2. [Kasiski examination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasiski_examination): Exploiting the repeated words in the ciphertext to figure out the key length in Vigenere Cipher.
3. [Friedman test aka Kappa Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher#Friedman_test): Measures the unevenness of the cipher letter frequencies to break the Vigenere cipher.
4. [Key elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher#Key_elimination): Eleminate the key by XORing two plaintexts with the same key.

Comment: You seem to target Vigenère ciphers, but Ned was asking for attacks on substitution. These do not immediately translate, as well; this is why they're listed precisely like you listed them, on the Vigenère wikipedia page.

Comment: @Joost Vigenere Cipher is a substitution Cipher, so the answer fits in perfectly.

Comment: I agree that I (perhaps falsely) jumped to the conclusion that Ned was talking about a monoalphabetic substitution, but I still think that picking out Vigenere and attacking that instead is a gross over-specification. At the very least, it needs an "if your cipher is actually Vigenere" note.

Comment: @Joost I have done that (specifying that the attack is for Vigenere). Only the middle two are Vigenere specific, and I have mentioned it. The rest work for others as well.